# If magnetic flux moves in opposite directions, is there (by definition) repulsion?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there by definition repulsion when magnetic flux moves in opposite directions? As in, is it always the case?

To illustrate, take an example. The magnetic flux in middle of two bar magnets side by side will be in opposite directions, and "bend" outwards, or cancel out, forming null point. It will instead move through opposite pole on other magnet. That process in itself, when the opposing flux "collides", seems like it should be repulsive force. That there is net attraction is clear, but is there also weak repulsive force from "bending" the flux, at the point where that happens (in turn causing flux to bend and cause attraction)? It seems like there would be if, by definition, there is repulsive force when magnetic flux moves in opposite directions.

[image]

Comment: The flux doesn’t move. You mean that the fields of the magnets point in opposite directions in between the magnets.

Comment: the magnetic flux lines are in opposite direction in between the magnets, yes

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480120/207455

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate. it is precisely defined.

Comment: police away, or do as you want. this question is well defined and precise.

Comment: you control yourself, I do not. do as you want.

Comment: When your previous question was put on hold, did you see this? “If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.” You are expected to improve the old question, not post a new question.

Comment: The previous question was clear, it was seen as a bit naive if anything. If you look at question overall on this stack exchange you have a couple that are that basic. Since the intent was not to have the basics answered but more if it was "per definition", in all cases, so that opposite flux is repulsive force, I asked that instead. The previous question is still valid, as long as there is very naive simple questions on this se, which there are.